# Extract strings after certain value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing strings. Is there a way to extract strings after certain value. For example.

```
df

Col
2017-09-19.I.L_WAY
2017-09-19.I.L_TEMP
```

Is there a way to extract

```
df1

Col                       Col1        Col2
2017-09-19.I.L_WAY      2017-09-19  I.L_WAY  
2017-09-19.I.L_TEMP     2017-09-19  I.L_TEMP
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) separate** Using `df` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end use `separate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(Col, c("Col1", "Col2"), sep = "\\.", extra = "merge", remove = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
                  Col       Col1     Col2
1  2017-09-19.I.L_WAY 2017-09-19  I.L_WAY
2 2017-09-19.I.L_TEMP 2017-09-19 I.L_TEMP
```

**2) as.Date/sub**  This creates a `Date` class column `Col1` and a character class column `Col2` without using any packages.

```
transform(df, Col1 = as.Date(Col), Col2 = sub("[^.]+\\.", "", Col),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
                  Col       Col1     Col2
1  2017-09-19.I.L_WAY 2017-09-19  I.L_WAY
2 2017-09-19.I.L_TEMP 2017-09-19 I.L_TEMP
```

**3) read.table** This is another base R alternative.  Replace the first dot with a semicolon, read it `df$Col` assuming semicolon separated fields and cbind that with `df`:

```
cbind(df, read.table(text = sub("\\.", ";", df$Col), sep = ";", as.is = TRUE,
  col.names = c("Col1", "Col2")))
```

giving:

```
                  Col       Col1     Col2
1  2017-09-19.I.L_WAY 2017-09-19  I.L_WAY
2 2017-09-19.I.L_TEMP 2017-09-19 I.L_TEMP
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Col
2017-09-19.I.L_WAY
2017-09-19.I.L_TEMP"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a question here. Actually if you observe there are 2 dots in the string  2017-09-19.I.L_WAY. So how it extracts exactly into 2017-09-19 and .I.L_WAY

Comment: In (1) `extra = "merge"` tells it to merge remaining fields.  In (2) `as.Date`  ignores garbage and `sub` only looks for the first occurrence.  In (3) same comment regarding `sub`.

Comment: Perfect thanks. One thing I can refer regular expressions in R for more details right? It is a part of regular expressions right

Comment: Regular expressions come with R. See `?regex` for details.

Comment: I tried with ````df %>%
  separate(Col, c("Col1", "Col2"), sep = "\\.", extra = "merge", remove = FALSE)````. But Col2 is returning NA

Comment: @DevP edit your question and share output of `dput(head(df,2))`. Using that, we can make sure our answers work for you.

Comment: Copy the code in the Note to the clipboard and paste it into a fresh R session. Then do the same for the code in the body and you will get the output shown.  Now , if you are trying it with a different input determine how the input you have differs from that shown in the Note. Does it have the same classes?  Does the content not conform to what was assumed?  etc.  If you can build a reproducible example that illustrates this similar to the Note in the answer then we can help.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `strsplit` from `base R`

```
df[c("Col1", "Col2")] <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(df$Col, "(?<=\\d)\\.", perl = TRUE))

df
#                 Col       Col1     Col2
#1  2017-09-19.I.L_WAY 2017-09-19  I.L_WAY
#2 2017-09-19.I.L_TEMP 2017-09-19 I.L_TEMP
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Col = c("2017-09-19.I.L_WAY", "2017-09-19.I.L_TEMP"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stringr`:

```r
cbind(df, data.frame(stringr::str_split_fixed(df$Col, pattern = '\\.', n = 2)))
```

```
#                   Col         X1       X2
# 1  2017-09-19.I.L_WAY 2017-09-19  I.L_WAY
# 2 2017-09-19.I.L_TEMP 2017-09-19 I.L_TEMP
```

Another Option using `tidyr`:

```r
tidyr::extract(df, Col, c("Col1", "Col2"), '^(.*?)\\.(.*)', convert=TRUE)
```